# remove specific validator from the formgroup in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am looking to remove the specific validator from validator array in order to set the controls again when some values changed.

I know normal solution where I need to set validators again and again.

```js
checked(event: MatCheckboxClickAction): void {
    const control = (this.form.get(
        'information',
    ) as FormGroup).controls.data1;
    if (event) {
        this.updateRequiredValidator(control);
    } else {
        control.setValidators([
            Validators.maxLength(9), Validators.minLength(2)
        ]);
        control.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
}

updateRequiredValidator(control: AbstractControl): void {
    control.setValidators([
        Validators.required,
        ...(control?.validator ? [control?.validator as ValidatorFn] : []),
    ]);
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

I would like to just removed the Validators.required on else part instead of setting validators again and again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the best bet is use a "customValidator" like "requireIf".

```
  requiredIf(field: string) {
    return (control: FormControl):{required:boolean}|null => {
      const form = control.parent as FormGroup;
      const check=form?form.get(field):null
      if (form && check && check.value)
        return !control.value ? { required: true } : null;

      return null;
    };
  }
//e.g.
this.form=new FormGroup({
   check:new FormControl();
   data1:new FormControl(null,this.requiredIf('check'))
})
```

But be carefull, when check change you need use

```
this.form.get('data1').updateValueAndValidity()
```

in [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wrfhow?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts) I use mat-angular and use the (change) to make the updateValueAndValidity

**UPDATE** to defined the typedef of the function

```
requiredIf(field: string):ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl):{required:boolean}|null => {
      ....
    }
}
```

Comment: just a small question.. How it can work for nested groups?

Comment: form = new FormGroup({
   check: new FormControl(true),
    val: new FormGroup({
       check: new FormControl(true),
    }),
    data1: new FormControl(null, [
      this.requiredIf("val.check"),
      Validators.maxLength(10)
    ])
  });

Comment: Type '(control: FormControl) => { required: boolean;} | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'. Types of parameters 'control' and 'control' are incompatible. I do get following error in the stackblitz.

Comment: app, If is in a nested group you need "get" the form, you should use parent.parent, e.g. if your formgroup is `{form:{check,{some:data1}}`,  and you can use in get the dot notation, e.g. `form('subgroup.check')`. If you get an error in your validator, use `AbstractControl` instead FormControl

Comment: thanks a lot.. just quick question.. what is return type of this function as I am following typedef for all methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out.Is that work for multi field? I was trying to expand the logic to work if 2 checkbox are selected then only make that required.

Comment: the logic is the same, you need "get" the two checkbox (first find the formgroup, then the two checkbox using get())

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding and removing the validators, you can create the custom validator function that can check all possible error and set error using `setError` method of `AbscractControl`

Comment: but I need to remove the validators.required based on the check condition

Comment: you can put custom validator on FormGroup it self