# How can i add/remove validators conditionally in reactive forms?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a reactive form like this

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  ...
  email: [],
  receiveNewsletter: [],
  ...
})
```

I want all fields to be optional, except if user checks `receiveNewsletter`, the email field should be required. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to watch the value of the checkbox and add or remove the required validator based on the value of `receiveNewsletter`

```
this.form.controls.receiveNewsletter.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   if(value){
      this.form.controls.email.addValidators(Validator.required);
   } else {
      this.form.controls.email.removeValidators(Validator.required);
   }
   this.form.controls.email.updateValueAndValidity(); //remember to add this to update the form control state
})
```

Comment: I suggest another approach, a [custom validator "requiredIf"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012294/remove-specific-validator-from-the-formgroup-in-angular/65013492#65013492)